# Математическая функция "сигнум"

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду, правильно ли оформлен код, или я не правильно использую математическую функцию `Math.signum(a)`?
Вот задача:

- В переменной n лежит некоторое вещественное число.
- Вычислить и вывести на экран значение функции «сигнум» от этого числа (-1, если число отрицательное; 0, если нулевое; 1 если, положительное).

---

```
public class Signum {
    public static void  main(String args[]){
       final double a = 3;
       final double b = 0;
       final double c = -3;
       double signum_a = Math.signum(a);
       double signum_b = Math.signum(b);
       double signum_c = Math.signum(c);
       System.out.println(signum_a);
       System.out.println(signum_b);
       System.out.println(signum_c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Результат-то правильный?

Comment: Результат правильный, но я бы считывал число n с консоли.

Comment: а не подскажите как правильно считывать число n  с консоли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это учебное задание, то, скорее всего, вы сами должны вычислить сигнум.

> ```
> return n == 0 ? 0 : n < 0 ? -1 : 1
> ```

PS: Ввод с консоли осуществляется так:

> ```
> Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
> int n = in.nextInt();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам сказано сделать это учебное задание на Java, то всё верно. Зачем самому придумывать велосипед, если есть библиотека, в которой это реализовано уже. Всё верно.